# Javers not persisting false boolean values

Tags: javers

When persisting objects with `boolean` fields the field and value are not persisted in the audit snapshot if the value is set to `false`. If the value is updated to a `true` value the field now appears in the snapshot with the `true` value. Switching the `boolean` to a `Boolean` works as expected but is not type we would like to use. Is this intended functionality or is there anyway to force javers to persist the `false` value in the snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Javers has a set of defaults that it checks against, it will only persist non default values. There's a default for `boolean` but not `Boolean`.

Comment: false is the default value for `boolean` in Java, what's the purpose of persisting it?

Comment: The main reason was the fact that the fields in the state could possibly not reflect all the fields present in the current model. For instance if that field was eventually removed you wouldn't be able to tell from the snapshot if it went from false to non existent. When we first encountered this behavior we couldn't tell if it was by design or not but is trivial for us to handle.

Comment: it's by design, to save storage space

Comment: @BartekWalacik I would also like to add that as a brand new user of JaVers, this is little bit confusing and inconsistent. The very first time a change happens the boolean config (fields) are saved even if "false". Then somebody changes the config to "true" and that is correctly represented. Now changing it back to "false" just removes it completely from the snapshot. For properties of business domain objects, the version history becomes quite confusing to follow in this specific case. Great lib overall tho.

Comment: @TaimurAhmedQureshi if you want to distinguish between null and false why not use Boolean?